# Using Firefox XML DOM to parse XML(RSS)

Tags: javascript, xml, firefox, dom

Any example on how to parse/have access to simple RSS feed elements in JS?
I don't want to use any Microsoft specific objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have XML in a string, you can parse it using the following in Firefox:

```
var xmlStr = "<test>Hello world</test>";
var parser = new DOMParser();
var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(xmlStr, "text/xml");
alert(xmlDoc.documentElement.nodeName);
```

If you've got your XML from an `XMLHttpRequest`, the `responseXML` property of the request will be a reference to an XML document.